# Результаты выборов в модераторы 2023

Tags: обсуждение, выборы, вехи

[Выборы модераторов #5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5) на Stack Overflow на русском подошли к концу, голоса подсчитаны, и новыми модераторами стали:

[image: aepot] [image: αλεχολυτ]

Вскоре они присоединятся к [существующей команде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) — пожалуйста, поблагодарите их за волонтёрство и поделитесь с ними своей помощью и советами, пока они осваивают азы!

Для получения подробностей о том, как проходило голосование, вы можете скачать результаты выборов [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5) или [посмотреть сводный отчёт онлайн](https://www.opavote.com/results/5845888772603904) (страница на английском).

Answer (score 19):

#### Поздравляю избранников!

##### Да прибудет с вами здравый смысл и объективность )

Comment: Спасибо, буду стараться.

Comment: [Всё будет хорошо](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vBVk.jpg)

Comment: И ещё активность

Answer (score 12):

Спасибо за доверие. Рассчитываю, имея ромб, сделать сайт лучше, активнее и удобнее.

Чтобы лучше становилось быстрее, продуктивнее, осознаннее и с пользой для как можно большего круга участников, хотел бы попросить вас оставить личный отзыв. Пожелания, предложения, замечания и любые другие слова, которые хотели, но стеснялись высказать, приветствуются.

Сообщения можно оставить [анонимно по ссылке](https://tellonym.me/user.9506949) или, даже комментарием здесь под постом (если сохранение личной анонимности вас не заботит).

Анонимные сообщения по умолчанию не публикуются открыто, если не планируется мой ответ на них.

Надеюсь увидеть сообщения не только от тех, кто поддержал меня голосом, но и от тех, кто проголосовал "против" на этапе предварительного голосования или просто не отранжировал меня в списке кандидатов на финальном этапе голосования. Если вы вовсе не голосовали на этих выборах, тоже пишите, будет интересно узнать почему. Не зная причин, почему вы проголосовали против, мне будет труднее стать лучше в ваших глазах.

Жду ваших откликов. Спасибо!

Comment: Отклик: мои поздравления и наилучшие пожелания обоим победителям.

Comment: Одним из моих запросов является чуть большая открытость и активность мод.состава в жизни сообщества. Я понимаю, что предъявлять данное требование ко всем и каждому конкретно модератору не совсем этично. Тем не менее хотелось бы понимать отношение мод.состава к происходящему в жизни сообщества и текущим проблемам. Ситуация, которая предшевствовала выборам была мягко говоря не самой лучшей в этом плане. Сейчас, по моим лично ощущениям, стало немного лучше. Но в данном вопросе важнее сохранить запал и энергию на длинную дистанцию. Если сейчас палить из всех орудий, то можно быстро перегореть.

Comment: @МихаилРебров мне кажется, что этот комментарий достоен отдельного поста (ответа) в этой ветке. Хотя при желании, можно и вовсе развернуть на самостоятельный вопрос.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я могу расскатать на целый вопрос (мне было что добавить). Заодно и будет площадка, для того, чтобы выработать видение того, что сообщество хочет видеть от модераторов и что они могут дать (а чего нет .. и почему). Только я не обещаю, что сегодня вечером это успею сделать. Я еще на больничном и сил у меня не так, чтобы очень много.

Comment: @МихаилРебров лёгкий этап выборов пройден - теперь пахать? :)

Comment: _слова которые стеснялись высказать_ Главное, чтоб вам нравилось, то что вы делаете, это очень важно и это не просто слова. Успехов вам в продвижении, тк невооруженным глазом заметно для пользователей все действия и когда замечаешь полезные, то понимаешь и поддерживаешь даже мысленно(а это важно) видишь некую коэрантность, а уж тем более, если становишься публичной более врезается в глаза. По моему также важно, не просто показать значимость и авторитет, а получать удовольствие от проделанной работы/помощи/поддержки SO и продвигать сайт на русском, ну и самое главное ```БУДЬТЕ ПРОЩЕ ГОСПОДА```.

Comment: *кто проголосовал "против"* это я, да я голосовала против вас (я вообще вас не знаю, оценка была по вашей кандидатуре и тому, как вы себя представили), прочитав вашу анкету и посмотрев вашу активность.  Будем надеяться что я ошибусь, ведь вас выбрали большинство, а значит те кто голосовали знали, за что выбирают. Почему проголосовала против, возможно повторюсь, но вы ведь хотите стать лучше... Потому что важно не доказать свое присутствие и пользоваться приоритетами,а добросоветсно быть **лицом** сообщества по миру от русскоязычных **программистов**. Удачи

Comment: Реквестирую драку с Грунди на ножах (¬‿¬ )

Comment: @Suvitruf подозрительно [похожий](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63601019#63601019) смайлик. Как будто бы кто-то чей-то твинк. Надо пробить по IP.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Грунди доппельгангер.

Answer (score 10):

Подсчёт бюллетеней, используя [Meek STV](https://blog.opavote.com/2017/04/meek-stv-explained.html). За 2 места борются 10 кандидатов. Количество бюллетеней составляет 366.

На приведенных ниже столбчатых диаграммах показано количество голосов за каждого кандидата в каждом туре.

- Жёлтый — Голоса, полученные в предыдущем туре.
- Зеленый — Голоса, полученные в этом туре.
- Красный — Голоса, перераспределённые в этом туре.

Голоса кандидата в одном туре - это сумма жёлтых и зелёных полосок. Поскольку зелёная и красная полоски обозначают перераспределённые голоса, сумма зелёных и красных полосок одинакова.

---

[image: Туры выборов]

Comment: transferring тут я бы скорее как "перераспределение" перевел, а не как "передача"

Comment: @insolor Ок, в следующий раз не стесняйтесь править

Comment: Я не 100% уверен в правильности перевода, оставил на ваше усмотрение.

Comment: Строго говоря, перераспределёнными являются как красные, так и зелёные голоса...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Да, в последнем абзаце так и написано…

Answer (score 4):

Хотелось бы поздравить и напомнить, что мы верим в вас, @aepot и @αλεχολυτ. Все у вас получится на вашем новом поприще. Вы уже внесли ощутимый вклад в развитие сообщества (о чем говорит ваша репутация и количество голосов за вас отданные), и теперь у вас есть еще больше возможностей для того, чтобы развивать его дальше.

Хочется также сказать спасибо всем, кто принял участие как выдвиженец, и всем кто голосовал. Всем неравнодушным и участливым членам ruSO.

Answer (score 3):

Поздравляю! Хорошие модераторы и будут хорошо работать на благо общества! Надеюсь разберутся с людьми которые просто так минусуют вопросы новичков и вообще поднимут сайт на новый уровень! Хорошей работы!

Comment: К сожалению (а может и к счастью) модераторы не видят, кто где как голосовал. Поэтому разобраться с минусаторами раз на раз не получится.

Answer (score 2):

## Поздравляю победителей!

На мете во время выборов обсуждали (куда-то удалили?), что необходимо обновить информацию по 3-ему этапу, вместо 3-х мест теперь на сайте список, в который можно поместить и ранжировать всех кандидатов.
Судя по бюллетеням многие так и сделали, либо же выставили 3-х фаворитов.

Но зачем это всё — не понятно.
Возникло подозрение, что учитывается только первое место. Если абстрагироваться от ранжирования и взять только первые места, то получим те же результаты что в [Round 1](https://www.opavote.com/results/5845888772603904#anchor-1):

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'https://www.opavote.com/ballots/5845888772603904/0'
soup = BS(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')
high_rank = [i.parent.text[2:] for i in soup.find_all('div', class_="rank", string='1')]

score = {}
for i in high_rank:
    if i not in score:
        score[i] = 1
    else:
        score[i]+=1
for k,v in score.items():
    score[k] = round(score[k] / len(high_rank) * 100, 1)

score
```

###### Вывод:

```
{'nomnoms12': 8.7,
 'EzioMercer': 3.6,
 'Roman Grinyov': 2.5,
 'αλεχολυτ': 31.4,
 'Михаил Ребров': 13.4,
 'Denis640Kb': 6.3,
 'Kromster': 9.0,
 'DiMithras': 3.0,
 'aepot': 19.7,
 'Total Pusher': 2.5}
```

Иначе говоря, ранжировать не было никакого смысла, учитывается только первое место. Может быть в следующий раз не стоит вводить избирателей в заблуждение и предложить выбор только одного кандидата?

И зачем туры (rounds) тоже не понятно, результат [девятого](https://www.opavote.com/results/5845888772603904#anchor-9) в общем-то ничем не отличается от картины в первом.

---

##### UPD:

Ув. [Kromster](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/177188/kromster).

Попробуем учесть ранжирование.

Здесь `p` забирает rank из div и переворачивает его значение, т.е. забираем все значения по ранжированию в бюллетене.
Получаем примерно тот же принцип как на [Евровидении](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%C2%AB%D0%95%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%C2%BB#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B6%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8), конечно же, с некоторыми оговорками. У каждого голосующего вес не 1, а 55 `sum(p.values())`, которые распределяются по списку, и если участник голосует только за одного кандидата, он отдаёт ему максимальные 10 баллов, остальные не использует.

```python
p = {str(i+1):10-i for i in range(10)}
p[''] = 0
scores = [(i.parent.find(text=True, recursive=False)[1:], p[i.text]) for i in soup.find_all('div', class_="rank")]

score = {}
for i in scores:
    if i[0] not in score:
        score[i[0]] = i[1]
    else:
        score[i[0]] += i[1]

s = sum(score.values())
for k,v in score.items():
    score[k] = round(score[k] / s * 100, 1)
```

###### Вывод:

```
'nomnoms12': 12.5
'Denis640Kb': 8.2
'aepot': 16.7          ⇚
'DiMithras': 5.0
'EzioMercer': 6.1
'Михаил Ребров': 12.7
'Total Pusher': 5.5
'Roman Grinyov': 5.1
'Kromster': 11.9
'αλεχολυτ': 16.5       ⇚
```

Как видим, победители те же, но отрыв уже не такой существенный.

Comment: *"подозрение, что учитывается только первое место. Если абстрагироваться от ранжирования и взять только первые места, то получим те же результаты"* - а еще можно абстрагироваться от результатов вовсе и **отсортировать кандидатов по алфавиту - тоже только первые 2 места прошли**. *"Может быть в следующий раз не стоит вводить избирателей в заблуждение .."* xD

Comment: @Kromster про алфавит смешно, да xD Тем не менее, смысла заморачиваться и ранжировать не было никакого )

Comment: Смысл был и есть, просто тут так совпало, что и алфавит и первоначальные преференции совпали. А могло выйти и иначе.

Comment: @Kromster да причём тут алфавит ) Просто если есть ранжирование, логично было бы давать 10 баллов на 1 место, 9 баллов за второе и т.д. Да это на результатах не отразилось бы, но хотя бы ранжирование было бы не бес толку.

Comment: Обрати внимание на то *как* (кому) переходят голоса от непрошедших кандидатов (особенно 3,5,6,9 раунды). Попробуй провести мысленный эксперимент и показать, при каких вводных данных ранжирование бы повлияло на итог. Подсказка, например в 9 раунде второе место достаточно легко могло бы быть другим.

Comment: @Kromster дополнил пост.

Comment: Давайте еще раз (вот тут все по шагам и с дампами данных https://www.opavote.com/results/5845888772603904), простой пример - 9 раунд, "лишние" голоса от αλεχολυτ переходят по большей части к aepot (т.к. в основном у тех кто ставил αλεχολυτ на первое место, на следующих местах был aepot). Однако мы легко можем представить, что если бы вторым по предпочтению у избирателей αλεχολυτ был бы Михаил Ребров, то он мог бы получить заметно больший прирост и обогнать aepot. Вот для этого ранжирование и применяется. Если этот вопрос вас сильно волнует - мб стоит задать отдельный вопрос.